# How can I generate a report file (ODF, PDF) from a django view

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to generate a report file from a view&template in django.
Preferred file formats would be OpenOffice/ODF or PDF.

What is the best way to do this?

I do want to reuse the page layout defined in the template, possibly by redefining some blocks in a derived template.

Ideally, the report should be inserted into an existing template file so I can provide the overall page layout, headers and footer in the generated output format.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177799/what-is-a-good-pdf-report-generator-tool-for-python.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, as I am looking for a way to re-use my django templates. Thanks for the hint though.

Answer (score 4):

[pisa/xhtml2pdf](http://www.htmltopdf.org/) should get you covered for PDF.  It even includes an example Django project.

Answer (score 3):

Try ReportLab for PDF output:

http://www.reportlab.org/